# Symfony backend <title>

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, slots

I use Symfony 1.4.11. And I need to add  custom `<title></title>` for each page.In frontend I use slots ([here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/04)) But I need also  to do same in my backend... How to do this? Use generator.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slots. Another way it to use config files if the page titles are static. Eg:

apps/frontend/modules/[module name]/config/view.yml

```
indexSuccess:
  metas:
    title: Your custom page title here
```

Comment: thank you! but how it use in backend? I have **Template: autoSfGuardUser … indexSuccess.php**

Comment: Same way as in the frontend. create a apps/backend/modules/[module name]/config directory, and add a view.yml file to it.

Comment: For internationalization, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714034/how-to-internationalize-metas-such-as-title-in-view-yml